# dexiejs query get slower overtime

Tags: progressive-web-apps, svelte, indexeddb, vite, dexie

So I am using Svelte+Vite with Dexiejs as my offline Db and Routify for the routes, when I go to a page that is making query to Dexiejs the response is pretty quick on the first request, but when I go to another page and go back to to the same page the response time gets slower each query.

I've used the index like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64053322/11504571) answer suggest. but it still happens. what did i miss ? can anyone recommend any alternatives that have better performance than dexiejs or pouchDB for offline db ? I am currently trying pouchDB as alternative

here is my code

```
let taskDone;
let taskOngoing;
let clustercount;
let tasks = [];
onMount(async function () {
        // @ts-ignore
        let clusterQuery = await db.cluster.reverse().sortBy("id");

        clustercount = clusterQuery.length;

        for (const clusters of clusterQuery) {
            // @ts-ignore
            taskDone = await db.task
                .where("[cluster_id+status]")
                .anyOf([clusters.id, 1], [clusters.id, 2])
                .toArray();

            // @ts-ignore
            taskOngoing = await db.task
                .where({ cluster_id: clusters.id })
                .toArray();

            tasks = [
                {
                    cluster_id: clusters.id,
                    count_done: taskDone.length,
                    count_ongoing: taskOngoing.length,
                    cluster_name: clusters.name,
                },
                ...tasks,
            ];
            count++;
        }
        dispatch("showList", tasks);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `tasks` array is being filled more and more for every time onMount is called. Is it a globally declared variable? Was it meant to be local?

Comment: hmmm the task showed on the page has a constant length though, so I don't think it keeps being filled more, and it is a global variable, I declared it outside onmount as such ```let tasks = []``` , I want it to be declared as empty array when I access the page and insert it with onmount